# HABTM Form not working in rails. Not submiting into Join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to assign a team to a player. A player can have many teams but upon initial set up they only have one. I am trying to set up a choice so the user can pick a team.

When I submit the form the data for the other fields, first_name and last_name submit fine however no data gets saved in the join table. I am using a select box however check boxes will do the job too if someone can think of that.

### Models

I have 2 models. Players and Teams set up with a HABTM relationship.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams

class Team< ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :players
```

### Controller

```
  def new
@player = Player.new
end

def create
@player = Player.new(params[:player])
if @player.save
  flash[:notice] = "Player Created"
  redirect_to(:action =>'list')
else
  render('new')
end
end
```

### Join table

I can insert data into the the join table from the rails console. I can then get this data and show it. So the relationships work.

```
create_table "players_teams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
t.integer "player_id"
t.integer "team_id"
end

add_index "players_teams", ["player_id", "team_id"], :name =>  "index_players_teams_on_player_id_and_team_id"
```

### View

In my view I have this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

This loads a view with the teams Populated. Once submitted I get

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kvOmx3G5H1mqLMnEn6HS3a79+WQnIzfsUA3Dt0XHo1w=", "player"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Data", "email"=>"email@email.com"}, "teams"=>{"team_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"create player"}
```

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't do anything with params[:teams] in the create action. The team ids are not in the params[:player] hash ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where on the form are you putting the collection? Maybe it is a typo but is should be

```
<%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.collection_select(:team_ids, Team.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and you should get

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kvOmx3G5H1mqLMnEn6HS3a79+WQnIzfsUA3Dt0XHo1w=",   
  "player"=>{
    "first_name"=>"Test",
    "last_name"=>"Data",
    "email"=>"email@email.com",
    "team_ids"=>["1"]
   }, 
   "commit"=>"create player"
 }
```

which means that the team_ids attribute gets set by the form.

Comment: IT WORKS! I have been stuck on this for a WEEK! I can not thank you enough.

Comment: I have done! but can not upvote it! Now I have done this I can move on..... but right now I can celebrate with some Tribes: ascend. I think you should check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is incorrect. Since a player `has_and_belongs_to_many :teams`, the proper parameter is `team_ids`.  However, that should be an array, so you need something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select("team_ids[]", Team.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

I believe that should do it.

Comment: Using this it throws the following error.'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)'